# Grad school and pregnancy

Tags: graduate-school, masters, computer-science

I 'm planning to apply for Masters in Computer Science (Non-thesis). I 'm wondering if both, pregnancy and school, can be managed at the same time. Or is better to wait until I get my baby and then apply for the school. I 'm trying to learn from others experiences.

Comment: Completely up to you, there are even examples who did Ph.D. while giving birth to a child at the process.

Comment: Are you asking only about _being pregnant_ while studying (i.e., you would time it so that you give birth after graduating), or also about giving birth mid-course?

Comment: One of my professors gave birth to her daughter during her PhD. She's pretty successful now. Not that much to worry I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not female, I can't give direct evidence. However, there are a couple of things you might think about.

The first is your general health. If it is good, then the stress of pregnancy will most likely be manageable. Then your studies will also be manageable. Note that the stress can be both physical and mental.

The second, is stress itself. Both a pregnancy and a graduate education can add to your stress. If you have other stresses in your life (financial, ...) it can get pretty high. That isn't a recommendation against it, however, but a recommendation that you will need ways to manage stress. If you do this well already, then there is likely no problem, otherwise, find active stress reducing activities.

In fact, having something to think about other than your studies can actually be a help because of the way the mind works. If you do nothing but try to force your mind to action it can stall.

Also, it is probably a mistake to delay your dreams *unnecessarily*, either for a child or an education.

Answer (score 0):

I think that anyone is capable of going to school even while having a kid. All the more power to you and pride you would have! It could be hard but any person knows what they're capable of and if you think you are, why wait on having a kid or getting the degree/why choose between school and parenthood?

Answer (score 0):

It can absolutely be done but you should be realistic up front with yourself regarding the challenges. You know yourself best.

Anecdotally, in my graduate school there was a PhD student who ended up pregnant and gave birth at the end of her second year. She had to make some adjustments such as working from home more, video and voice conferencing with her advisors, but she made it work. One of the strongest students in the program.

I think this is a question that you decide the answer to.

Answer (score 0):

You should / could check in advance how open your university actually is. We are very supportive and try to help wherever possible, since many of our professors are young(er) parents as well, and sometimes we are stretching rules a bit which makes it much easier and reduces stress.

In general, having a kid during grad school might be wise, because when it comes o employment questions afterwards, you can always declare that you already have a kid ;-). (yes, I know that you should not be asked about it, but I know of several companies which are not employing younger women because of the risk of them becoming pregnant).

So in short: Do whatever feels good to you!